# Why GUI is a bad idea in a Linux Server?

Tags: linux, rhel, gui, x-server

I installed a Linux Server (RHEL-7) for one of my customer. Followed by that couple of users requested for installing Eclipse IDE in the server. I objected the idea of having GUI like Gnome in the server, quoting the reason that it is going to consume more resources. And it may result in opening-up additional ports etc.. Alternatives proposed was using Eclipse-with RRE or PyCharm enterprise. I am trying to understand what will be the strong argument point to avoid GUI installation in a Linux server. The only quick reference I found is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI

Thanks in advance

Comment: This really depends on what the server is used for.  I've seen servers host VNC sessions with full desktop environments.  I've seen servers that had X11-based applications that were used over ssh tunneling.  There's nothing fundamental about a server that suggest that it not have GUI applications.

Comment: X was designed to work with the Xserver installed at each client seat (or terminal) and the client applications installed to a central server so the centralized applications gathered in a single repo could connect as clients to the terminals calling them, each locally configured for any of many various configurations.

Answer (score 3):

Installing a GUI on a server is not necessarily bad. It depends on what the purpose of that server is. The server may be intended to run some graphical sessions for multiple users. Back in the day, when workstations were expensive and multiple X terminals were connected to one workstation, this was common.

If it is about security, your server may be big enough to run different virtual machines.

If the main purpose of the server is something different and it doesn't have enough resources for both, add another server.